# How to set country flag according to the local time of that country?

Tags: android

here i am created an radio app which is streaming in online i have save the shows images and titles in sqlite and retrieved them according to the following code

```
        final Cursor cView = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM proname WHERE FromTiming <= time('now', 'localtime')\n" + "" +
                    "AND ToTiming >= time('now', 'localtime')\n" + "ORDER BY FromTiming LIMIT 1", null);
```

now  i want to set the flag in front of my time displaying in my app like this :
(flag fromtime - totime)
i have created 4 columns in my database imageid,title,fromtime,totime

please help me.. to get the current country flag according to the country's local time..

Comment: be aware that there could be same local time in different countries

Comment: Ohh then what i have todo

Comment: You should show flag according to device's locale

Comment: how can i do that help me